# modifier + different char, Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, keyevent, modifiers

Let's say my application consists of Rich Text Box and a button. I want the button to be enabled when users press a key in RTB, but **it can't be** any of modifiers.

I can handle this in some KeyEvent like PreviewKeyDown, but it doesn't work when I press modifier + other char, for instance SHIFT + S, which is valid, cause the result is letter S. Is there a way to separate my demand or should I make use of some different approach? I could use TextChanged, but there are many more actions that I've already written and I would prefer to do it that way.

Simple explanation:

```
 private void richTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Alt && !e.Control && !e.Shift)
            {
                this.button1.Enabled = true;
                    else
                this.button1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's enough to check if your `RichTextBox` has text, then enable your button. so you can handle `TextChanged` event and check for `TextLength` property.

Comment: My richtextbox already has a text. I mean, it was just simple explanation, my case is more complicated, I need to know how to solve it when let's say richtextbox.text = "Something" and now now when I press Shift it's disabled, but when i press Shift+char it's enabled.

Comment: @RezaAgheai Yes, I know that, as I've written in a question. But in this particular case I can't use TextChanged, that's the problem.

Comment: So it seems using `KeyPress` event to enabling the button is enough for you, since modifiers and arrow keys , ...don't have any impact on `KeyPress`.

Comment: But you better consider `TextChanged` since the user can paste something in the `RichtextBox`, and this way none of key events will fire.

Comment: Did `KeyPress` solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [`KeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event Occurs when a character, space or backspace key is pressed while the control has focus and modifier keys has no impact on this event, it seems using `KeyPress` may help you.

But you better consider handling `TextChanged`event and checking `TextLength`, since the user can paste something in the RichtextBox, and this way none of key events will fire.